# how to set icon to QTreeView when indentation equals zero

Tags: qt, qtreeview

i use a treeview in my qt project. when i call setIndentation(0) all tree icons disappear.
how can i solve this problem?

```
QTreeView *treeView = new QTreeView(parent);
treeView->setIndentation(0);
```

Comment: What is the reason for setting zero indentation?

Comment: @vahancho: to make sure there is no indentation, I believe, e.g. not get an undefined behavior when the ratio does not match between the indentation and the icon size.

Comment: Sounds like a Qt bug to me. Does it work properly for setIndentation(1)?